# Reading from a nodejs object

Tags: javascript, nodejs, arrays, arbitrum

I try to read data from this node js object (I got it from sequencer feed on arbitrum):

```
data = [
  BigNumber { _hex: '0x0f634d1e114f4d', _isBigNumber: true },
  BigNumber { _hex: '0x01', _isBigNumber: true },
  [
    '0x82aF49447D8a07e3bd95BD0d56f35241523fBab1',
    '0x1F6d54109AE86Db5d2E34b5D51Bd1e7baD20f95d'
  ],
  '0xf1C75b19EF1A1c6fCd7fF3444496D5c8D496bf09',
  BigNumber { _hex: '0x64d14d42', _isBigNumber: true },
  amountIn: BigNumber { _hex: '0x0f634d1e114f4d', _isBigNumber: true },
  amountOutMin: BigNumber { _hex: '0x01', _isBigNumber: true },
  path: [
    '0x82aF49447D8a07e3bd95BD0d56f35241523fBab1',
    '0x1F6d54109AE86Db5d2E34b5D51Bd1e7baD20f95d'
  ],
  to: '0xf1C75b19EF1A1c6fCd7fF3444496D5c8D496bf09',
  deadline: BigNumber { _hex: '0x64d14d42', _isBigNumber: true }
]
```

I try to read for example amountIn like this:

```
let amountIn= data[0]?.amountIn;
```

but amountIn is undefined all the time...
I also tried it with this commands:

```
let amountIn= data[0].amountIn;
amountIn = data.find((item) => item.amountIn)?.amountIn;
```

Can someone tell me how to read from an object like this one?

Thank you!

---

I am decoding the transaction, which are looking like this:

```
{
  type: 2,
  chainId: 42161,
  nonce: 74,
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x3b9aca00', _isBigNumber: true },
  maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x47868c00', _isBigNumber: true },
  gasPrice: null,
  gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x0c3160', _isBigNumber: true },
  to: '0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564',
  value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x989680', _isBigNumber: true },
  data: '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',
  accessList: [],
  hash: '0xeafc39e31f7d4f77a57259608d2da26c7243d6b8e3bd032b4993542659235753',
  v: 0,
  r: '0xcca1f3f3cd0e308e55758bd15c9cc518ed4e9603ec9389c65fbf4238d0b0d90e',
  s: '0x0e21c108ad82a3fc4890e6ec9b7bd1f5ee4bfc6414b300d15552e46cb7593df0',
  from: '0x0922a4F1f520dB129A86aB57a5Bd76cE568bA9c0'
}
```

and I am using just transaction.data now and decode it like this:

```
let decodedData = await interface_uniV3.decodeFunctionData(
          dex_details["UniV3"].interface.getFunction(tx.data.slice(0, 10)).name,
          tx.data
        );
```

where my interface is created  like this:

```
let interface_uniV3 = new ethers.utils.Interface(UniV3RouterABI);
```

with abis from this address on arbiscan https://arbiscan.io/address/0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564#code
And then the data is created like u can see above (Not exactly, it is another transaction but it works like that. (By the way, the used function is `exactInputSingle`

Comment: How did you obtained the `data` variable?

Comment: I am decoding a transaction data via router.interface.decodeFunctionData(functionName, transactionData)

Comment: Can you provide the code and the interface definition? What are you using to decode? web3, etherjs, something else, .. As the answer by EthanOK says, the `data` doesn't look right. It seems to be an array, but it has `amountIn:` that make it look like an object.

Comment: I have added a few details. Thank you for having a look

Comment: U got an idea for that?

Comment: I checked the other day. It confuses me that the decoding has a `path`, but `exactInputSingle` doesn't have such parameter. Perhaps, the abi is wrong, or the address is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`data` that you list is `array`. you can try amountIn=?data[5].

Comment: but it is not sure, that amountIn is on index 5 every time. That's why I wanted to access via name. Is that possible?

Comment: U got an idea for that?